# How to prevent from inserting special character using before insert trigger in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb

I need to prevent special characters from entering my table column using Before insert trigger in MariaDB. I can prevent from entering special character, but, if I do not want my trigger to execute if everything is valid during bulk insert.

What I am trying to do is like, if I am inserting 3 rows, and if 2 rows are valid and 1 invalid, 2 rows will get inserted. This is what I am trying to do

```
create trigger namecheck before insert on table
for each row
begin
 if (new.colname rlike '[^A-Za-z]') then signal sqlstate '12345' set message_text='wrong';
 end if;
end;
```

Comment: “*I do not want my trigger to execute if everything is valid during bulk insert*” How do you propose assessing the validity of “*everything*” without running this trigger, who’s purpose is seemingly just that? Do you not want this trigger to run at all during a `BULK INSERT`? Would you accept if the data being `BULK INSERT`ed violated the logic implemented in this trigger?

Comment: What I am trying to do is like, if I am inserting 3 rows, and if 2 rows are valid and 1 invalid, 2 rows will get inserted. This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Edited after you made it clear you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are not the same product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, MySQL triggers don't support the behavior you describe. If any row inserted by a given statement causes the trigger to throw an error, then all rows inserted by that statement are cancelled.

One possible workaround is to insert rows one at a time. Then the rows you want will insert successfully (one by one), and the rows that cause the signal will fail (one by one).

You can accomplish what you want while using a multi-row `INSERT` if you use a `CHECK` constraint and `INSERT IGNORE`, not a trigger.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (  
  colname varchar(100) check (colname not rlike '[^A-Za-z]')             
);    
                    
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable VALUES ('abc'), ('123');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

Warning (Code 3819): Check constraint 'mytable_chk_1' is violated.

SELECT * FROM mytable;
+---------+
| colname |
+---------+
| abc     |
+---------+
```

Unfortunately, you don't get a chance to define a custom error message this way.

`CHECK` constraints require MySQL 8.0.16 or later or MariaDB 10.2.1 or later.

---

Re your comments:

You have clarified that you are using MariaDB, not MySQL as originally stated in your question (I have edited the question to make it more clear).

Here is a working demo using MariaDB 10.4: https://dbfiddle.uk/D6D3S8-j

Comment: I am trying to add the check constraint but receiving error:

4025 - Constraint constr_name failed for tablename

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: 10.4.32-MariaDB

Comment: I am executing
alter table tablename add constraint con_name check (name not rlike '[^A-Za-z]')

Comment: @AbhishekChatterjee if the alter table is giving that error, you have existing data that violates the constraint.  You need to fix the data before adding the constraint.

Comment: (as a hack, you can exclude existing bad data from the constraint based on id, but only if you don't use auto_increment - though using a sequence works: https://dbfiddle.uk/18Lu6J7S)

Comment: I have tried your code using INSERT IGNORE, but, no valid row  is getting inserted if any invalid row is present during bulk insert

Comment: I provided a working demonstration for MariaDB 10.4. See the link I gave to the dbfiddle. I can't guess what you tried, so I will not comment on it.

Comment: Yeah your code is working fine, but , not with bulk insert what I said earlier. 
But thanks sir for helping this much. But is it possible to store that row which is invalid, in another table ? I mean when the check constraint will check invalid, at that time I want to store that invalid row in another table. Is that possible?

Comment: My code is using multi-row INSERT, for two rows. I demonstrated that it keeps the valid row and ignores the invalid row. I believe it works the same for any number of rows.  What do you mean by bulk insert?

Comment: Ask a new question for your other scenario of storing the row in another table. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions